# Woocommerce after checkout upload files

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Iam desperately trying to upload and update the file input field in woocommerce checkout page , but only after the order has been created , not before. So i tried different things but I don't understand why woocommerce can see only $_POST files and $_FILES are always empty in my function..

I don't use AJAX I would like to grab the file values from the form same as with $_POST. Any guides please ?

This is my approach:

***checkout-template.js***

```
    /**
     * Init checkout modifications template
     * @return void
     */
    public function init() {
       add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', [$this, 'saveCheckoutFields'], 10, 2);
       // There is no problem with the file input , it renders , it works
       // The thing that doesn't work is getting the value back in backend , in frontend i can see the files from the input in console
       // wc form has already the tag enctype='multipart/form-data'
       add_filter('woocommerce_form_field', [$this, 'woocommerce_file_form_field'], 10, 4);
    }

----------

     /**
     * Filter function to implement a file input for woocommerce
     */
    public function woocommerce_file_form_field($field, $key, $args, $value) {
        // Only modify if the field type is 'file'
        if('file' == $args['type']) {
            $max_size = isset($args['max_size']) ? 'data-max_size="'.intval($args['max_size'] * 1024 * 1024).'" ' : '';
            $accept = isset($args['accept']) ? 'accept="'.esc_attr($args['accept']).'" ' : '';
            $multiple = isset($args['multiple']) ? 'multiple' : '';
            $fileInfoLabel = isset($args['file_info_label']) ? esc_html($args['file_info_label']) : esc_html__('Vă rugăm să încărcați documentele!', 'woocommerce');
            $maxSizeLabel = isset($args['max_size_label']) ? esc_html($args['max_size_label']) : esc_html__('Dimensiunea maximă a fiecărui fișier nu trebuie sa depășească 10MB. Se pot încărca maximum 5 fișiere.', 'woocommerce');
            $inputLabel = isset($args['input_label']) ? esc_html($args['input_label']) : esc_html__('Încarcă fișierul', 'woocommerce');

            $fieldInput = sprintf(
                '<input type="%s" class="input-file %s" %s name="%s" id="%s" %s/>',
                esc_attr($args['type']),
                esc_attr(implode(' ', $args['input_class'])),
                $multiple,
                esc_attr(empty($multiple) ? $key : $key.'[]'),
                esc_attr($args['id']),
                $max_size.$accept
            );

            $fieldInputHolder = sprintf('<input type="hidden" name="%s" id="%s" >', esc_attr($key).'_holder', esc_attr($key).'_holder');

            $field = '<div class="form-row form-row-wide form-upload">
                <span class="file-text">'.$fileInfoLabel.'</span>
                <div class="form-row-error"></div>
                <div class="form-row-filelist is-hidden"></div>
                <div class="file-input-container">
                    '.$fieldInput.'    
                    '.$fieldInputHolder.'                  
                    <label class="label-upload" for="'.esc_attr($key).'">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="17" viewBox="0 0 16 17" fill="none">
                            <path d="M14.2222 0.190063H1.77778C0.8 0.190063 0 0.990063 0 1.96784V14.4123C0 15.3901 0.8 16.1901 1.77778 16.1901H14.2222C15.2 16.1901 16 15.3901 16 14.4123V1.96784C16 0.990063 15.2 0.190063 14.2222 0.190063ZM9.77778 12.6345H3.55556V10.8567H9.77778V12.6345ZM12.4444 9.07895H3.55556V7.30117H12.4444V9.07895ZM12.4444 5.5234H3.55556V3.74562H12.4444V5.5234Z" fill="white" />
                        </svg>'.$inputLabel.'</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row-info">
                    <span class="file-info">'.$maxSizeLabel.'</span>
                </div>
            </div>';
        }

        if($args['return']) {
            return $field;
        } else {
            echo $field;
        }
    }

----------

public function saveCheckoutFields($order_id,$data) {
        // simple fields
        $additional_simple_fields = [
            'motivul_consultatiei',
            'recomandare_consult',
            'alte_consultatii',
        ];

        // select fields
        $additional_select_fields = [
            'tipul_consultatiei'
        ];

        // file input holder
        $additional_file_field = [
            'documente_medicale_file'
        ];

        // Save normal fields - ok
        foreach($additional_simple_fields as $field) {
            if(isset($_POST[$field]) && !empty($_POST[$field])) {
                $sanitized_value = wp_kses($_POST[$field], 'post');
                update_post_meta($order_id, $field, $sanitized_value);
            }
        }

        // Save select fields - ok
        foreach($additional_select_fields as $field) {
            if(isset($_POST[$field]) && !empty($_POST[$field])) {
                update_post_meta($order_id, $field, sanitize_key($_POST[$field]));
            }
        }

        // Save file fileds - not ok
        foreach($additional_file_field as $field) {
            error_log("Files: ".print_r($_FILES[$field], true)); // this is empty

            if(isset($_FILES[$field]) && !empty($_FILES[$field])) {

                $files = $_FILES[$field];
                $file_count = count($files['name']);

                $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
                $user_path = '/wc_checkout_uploads/'.$order_id;
                $user_folder = $upload_dir['basedir'].$user_path;
                $user_url = $upload_dir['baseurl'].$user_path;

                if(!is_dir($user_folder)) {
                    wp_mkdir_p($user_folder);
                    chmod($user_folder, 0777);
                }

                for($i = 0; $i < $file_count; $i++) {
                    $file_name = $files['name'][$i];
                    $file_tmp = $files['tmp_name'][$i];

                    $file_path = $user_folder.'/'.basename($file_name);
                    $file_url = $user_url.'/'.basename($file_name);

                    // Check if the file already exists and handle accordingly
                    if(file_exists($file_path)) {
                        // Handle situation where file already exists (e.g., rename the file)
                        $file_name = wp_unique_filename($user_folder, $file_name);
                        $file_path = $user_folder.'/'.$file_name;
                        $file_url = $user_url.'/'.$file_name;
                    }

                    // Move the uploaded file to the destination
                    if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_path)) {
                        $file_urls[] = $file_url;
                    }
                }

                // I want to concatenate all urls of the files , in case there are multiple files
                $concatenated_urls = implode(',', $file_urls);
                error_log("Files: ".print_r($concatenated_urls, true));

                // Update post meta with concatenated file URLs
                update_post_meta($order_id, $field, $concatenated_urls);

            }

}
```

Comment: Can't tell where `woocommerce_file_form_field` actually executes here - but it only appears to return the HTML code for the specific field, not sure if that also somehow sets the correct `enctype` on the `form` element, that would be necessary for file uploads? That is the first thing you should go check on.

Comment: I edited the code , field is rendered corectly after billing form field , its still in the form tag , I can see in network that the field is sent , but it has no value and that's what I dont understand

Comment: Does the form element itself have the correct enctype set, `enctype="multipart/form-data"`? If that is not the case, then no actual file _upload_ will be performed, but only the file _name_ will be sent as a text value.

Comment: Man , it is set.. I tried with the ajax method to send the formData file inside and this way it works , but I want to send the file only after the order has been created so I can grab the order id and make a folder with the order id and the files inside.

Comment: File upload is only possible via Ajax in WooCommerce checkout, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76691778/3730754)… I don't think that you can *"send the file only after the order has been created"*…

Comment: That's why woocommerce didn't use file input , it is a mess. Thanks for answers!